# image change when radio on-change in radio button groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

i am having three tabs inside that i have set of radio buttons when click the radio button it will image of radio button .

But my problem is when i change image anywhere in tab it was reflect to first tab only ....please see this code and tell me proper way

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case '1':
                $(this).parents('#group').find(".good").attr('src', 'img/good1.png');
                $(this).parents('#group').find(".bad").attr('src', 'img/bad.png');
                break;
            case '3':
                $(this).parents('#group').find(".bad").attr('src', 'img/bad1.png');
                $(this).parents('#group').find(".good").attr('src', 'img/good.png');
                break;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="RatContent" id="tab1">
        <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 58vh">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row questionrow" id="group">
                    <div class="col col-80">
                        <h5>food was served hot and fresh?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-10">
                        <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="1" id="good" class="input-hidden" required />
                        <label for="good">
                            <img class="good" src="img/good.png">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-10">
                        <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="3" id="ok" class="input-hidden" required />
                        <label for="ok">
                            <img class="bad" src="img/bad.png">
                        </label>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </ion-scroll>
    </div>
    
    <div class="RatContent" id="tab2">
        <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 58vh">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row questionrow" id="group">
                    <div class="col col-80">
                        <h5>food was served hot and fresh?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-10">
                        <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="1" id="good" class="input-hidden" required />
                        <label for="good">
                            <img class="good" src="img/good.png">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-10">
                        <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="3" id="ok" class="input-hidden" required />
                        <label for="ok">
                            <img class="bad" src="img/bad.png">
                        </label>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </ion-scroll>
    </div>
    
    <div class="RatContent" id="tab3">
        <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 58vh">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row questionrow" id="group">
                    <div class="col col-80">
                        <h5>food was served hot and fresh?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-10">
                        <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="1" id="good" class="input-hidden" required />
                        <label for="good">
                            <img class="good" src="img/good.png">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-10">
                        <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="3" id="ok" class="input-hidden" required />
                        <label for="ok">
                            <img class="bad" src="img/bad.png">
                        </label>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </ion-scroll>
    </div>
```

Comment: i tried differnt id but its not working

Comment: u try and give me a code

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID attribute. ID is specified to appear on only one instance of an element in your entire page.

Comment: yeah i got but i want  something like ..when i move tabs and return to this tab the radio button still checked . i want that tabs all radio button should be not be checked

Comment: Why are you using the `parents()` method in this case. I'm unable to understand what you've really written here. Do you want to change the image when you click on Radiobutton / Image? Or What? 

It will be useful to mention what exactly do you want here.